# untar tar.gz doesn't work

Tags: tar, archive

I made an archive example.tar.gz at desktop. When I code like in desktop dir:

```
tar -zxvf example.tar.gz
```

The output is `etc/passwd`(the file I archieved)
and then

```
ls -al
```

example.tar.gz is still there. How can I extract this?

Comment: What's the output of `tar -tvzf example.tar.gz` for your file? Please [add](https://askubuntu.com/posts/964285/edit) it to your question using a code block (`{}` button).

Comment: `tar` doesn't automatically delete the archive like gzip or bzip2 does.

Comment: I don't want to delete. I made archieve with tar -czvf. And now I tried to extract with tar -zxvf but it doesn't work.

Comment: The default is that `tar` removes the first slash (/) in order to avoid overwriting important files by mistake. It uses a local path instead. Maybe this behaviour makes you confused. -- Did you check if the file `etc/passwd` exists. This is a local path (seen from the current directory), so use the command `ls -l etc/passwd` or if you wish `find . -name passwd` -- In other words, I think that 'untar' worked for you, the problem is probably, that you have not found the extracted file.

Comment: thank you so much. Yes it says it is in Desktop.

Comment: Are your problems with `tar` solved now, or is there some other problem left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is that **`tar`** removes the first slash (/) in order to avoid overwriting important files by mistake. It uses a local path instead. Maybe this behaviour makes you confused.

Did you check if the file `etc/passwd` exists? This is a local path (seen from the current directory), so use the command

```
ls -l etc/passwd
```

or if you wish

```
find . -name passwd
```

In other words, I think that 'untar' worked for you. The problem is probably, that you have not found the extracted file.